# Executable created by PyInstaller closes with no errors when calling matplotlib.pyplot.subplots if original conda environment isn't activated

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda3

I'm trying to create an executable using PyInstaller but am having trouble with matplotlib. When running the code from the IDE, it runs as expected. After creating the executable and running from command prompt, the program dies when creating the subplots. However, if I activate the conda environment that I wrote the program in, the program does run. This isn't ideal as I'd like to distribute the finished program without users having to worry about Python or Anaconda.

I assume that PyInstaller is missing some files and that I'll need to add them to the `datas` portion of my spec file, but I can't figure out which ones.

Here's some code I got from the matplotlib site that causes the same issue to happen:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_title('A single plot')
plt.show()
```

Here is my Pyinstaller spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import exec_statement
block_cipher = None
mpl_data_dir = exec_statement(
    "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib._get_data_path())")

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\rwardrup\\PycharmProjects\\MPLTest'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[(mpl_data_dir, 'matplotlib\\mpl-data')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='MPLTest',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='MPLTest')
```

I did some digging and, in Matplotlib's figure.py, in the `subplots` method,
`self.add_gridspec(nrows, ncols, figure=self, **gridspec_kw).subplots(sharex=sharex, sharey=sharey, squeeze=squeeze,subplot_kw=subplot_kw)`
is not returning anything.
`self.add_gridspec(nrows, ncols, figure=self, **gridspec_kw).subplots` by itself does, however.

Comment: what about your pyinstaller configuration?

Comment: Good call. Sorry about that. Added now.